# nohup for batch command using " for x in find "

Tags: batch-file, find, nohup, at-job

I am trying to run a Python script (qTrimHIV.py) on ALL the files ending in .fastq in the current directory. I'd like to append `nohup` at the beginning so that it does all the files out from a single command, and no matter if I close the terminal or logout.

The individual command:

```
for x in $(find . -name '*fastq'); do echo $x; python ../qTrimHIV.py -verbose -fastq $x -l 23 -m 20 -w 23 -o ${x%.fastq*}tr -mode 2; done
```

works well. But when I put nohup in front of the batch command:

```
nohup for x in $(find . -name '*fastq') ; do echo $x; python ../qTrimHIV.py -verbose -fastq $x -l 23 -m 20 -w 23 -o ${x%.fastq*}tr -mode 2; done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

I get the error above.

However, it works well if I put the nohup before the actual command "python ../qTrimHIV.py ", but this is not really what I want, as I want to submit the task for all files at once and have it running until it's done, without having to keep logged in.

I've tried

```
for x in $(find . -name '*fastq') ; do echo $x; python ../qTrimHIV.py -verbose -fastq $x -l 23 -m 20 -w 23 -o ${x%.fastq*}qtrim -mode 2; done | at now
```

but it doesn't let me see the progress of the job, and I can't know if it is still running or not.

Can anyone give me any suggestions? Should I use a different command, other than `nohup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
nohup bash -c 'your command, everything including for'
```

also, why not to run shell script using nohup:

```
nohup <your script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Icarus :) I am not familiar with writing shell scripts yet, but I should get to it.